# How to define a package once and use it in several pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, architecture

I'm newbie to Next.js and I have a question about the code structure.

I have two pages, `PostList (index.js)`, `PostSingle ([postId].js)`. I want to have a button that switches the theme dark/light in both pages. To do that, I used a package named `darkmode-js`.

The package will be inited like this:

```
  const options = {
    bottom: "64px",
    right: "32px",
    left: "unset",
    time: "0.5s",
    mixColor: "#fff",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    buttonColorDark: "#100f2c",
    buttonColorLight: "#fff",
    saveInCookies: false,
    label: "",
    autoMatchOsTheme: true,
  };

  const darkmode = new Darkmode(options);
  darkmode.showWidget();
```

I can import the package in both pages `import Darkmode from "darkmode-js";` and define the options in both pages `const options = {}` and call it `darkmode.showWidget();` in both pages separately like this:

```
import Darkmode from "darkmode-js";

const PostsList = (props) => {

    // All that package stuff here

    return ( ...
```

And

```
import Darkmode from "darkmode-js";

const PostsSingle = (props) => {

    // All that package stuff here

    return ( ...
```

But, it looks like a wrong structure to me. Any better idea to define a package once and use it in everywhere else needed?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new file (let's call it darkmode.js)
It should export your instance of darkmode, and you'll import it wherever you need.

```js
 import DarkMode from "darkmode-js";

 const options = {
    bottom: "64px",
    right: "32px",
    left: "unset",
    time: "0.5s",
    mixColor: "#fff",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    buttonColorDark: "#100f2c",
    buttonColorLight: "#fff",
    saveInCookies: false,
    label: "",
    autoMatchOsTheme: true,
  };

  const darkmode = new DarkMode(options);
  export default darkmode;
```

(Please note the export default, as this keyword will allow you to import this instance in other files)

Then, where you need it, you can just

```js
import darkmode from './path/to/your/darkmode.js'
const PostsSingle = (props) => {
   darkmode.showWidget();
   return (
```

Comment: Oh nice .. good